# Calculate total seconds from string in format "HH:mm:ss,fff"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-7-x64

In PowerShell V2, I want to calculate the total seconds and milliseconds of a given string.
My string is `00:03:56,908` and the desired output would be `236.908`

My working, but awkward code is

```
$a = "00:03:56,908"
$a = [datetime]::ParseExact($a,"HH:mm:ss,fff",$null)
[string]($a.Hour*3600 + $a.Minute*60 + $a.Second) +"."+ [string]$a.Millisecond
```

Is there a smarter / shorter way to achieve this?

---

All I found was .totalseconds from a TimeSpan object. But this code was even longer in my attempt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with the `TimeSpan` class in .NET versions earlier than 4.0 is that it's not handling different cultures or formatting strings very well. Given that your string has a comma instead of a period, we'll have to change that if we want to parse it to a timespan, but I think that's still the best way to go at it.

```
$timeString = "00:03:56,908"
$timeStringWithPeriod = $timeString.Replace(",",".")
$timespan = [TimeSpan]::Parse($timestringWithPeriod)
$totalSeconds = $timespan.TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Oh, I have control over the input string. is it shorter with a dot instead of a comma? Like `"00:03:56.908"`

Comment: Yes, then you can skip the second line of code above. You could even write it in one line: `[TimeSpan]::Parse("00:03:56.908").TotalSeconds`

Comment: I was too fast. Your idea from the comment gives me `236,908` instead of `236.908`. Beside a string.Replace is there another way to get a dot? Maybe something like -DontUseCulture? :)

Comment: The `TotalSeconds` property of the `TimeSpan` object is not a string, it's a double. Printing the double in the format you want should be simple using the `ToString` method, providing the format you want. Read more on the documentation pages on [Double.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.80).aspx) and [Double.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d8ztz0sa(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't shy away from `TotalSeconds`, it can be useful in this circumstance... and reasonably short, if you just extract that property:

```
PS C:\> $a = "00:03:56,908"
PS C:\> $a = [datetime]::ParseExact($a,"HH:mm:ss,fff",$null)
PS C:\> (New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date).Date -End $a).TotalSeconds
236.908
```

Putting `New-TimeSpan` in parenthesis allows us to evaluate that statement first, and then to extract `TotalSeconds` afterwards.  Using `(Get-Date).Date` is important because it defines midnight, and since you converted `$a` to a DateTime where the date is today, we need to use midnight today as our Start time.