# How to get YouTube video details (title, author, duration, etc.) through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, youtube, youtube-data-api

I've got this script:

```
param(
  [String]$VideoId
)

[String]$gdata_uri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$VideoId"

$metadata = irm $gdata_uri
$duration = $metadata.entry['media:group']['yt:duration'].seconds
echo $duration
```

that got the duration on seconds of a desired YouTube video, but since then the API has changed and it no longer works. I've getting an API key and swaping the old API link with the new API link: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$VideoId&key=<my_api_key>&part=contentDetails` but it still doesn't work, so some other things have been changed.

Could someone help adapt this script to work on the new API and also to get other info appart from the duration?

Comment: Your research should start with Q&A tagged [youtube-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3?sort=frequent)

Comment: SO is not a place where people rewrite someone else's code for you.

Comment: I mean, it really is not a complex script, it is just 10 lines it is not like I am plagiarazing months of work. I just wanted someone to help me point to the correct entries, but if it makes you happy, I'll change the drafting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working. Sorry if I wasted your time on my easy to answer question.

It was as simple as to change `$duration = $metadata.entry['media:group']['yt:duration'].seconds` to `$duration = $metadata.items.contentDetails.duration`, and adjust it for other info like author, you can figure out what to change by entering the API url in your browser.

Now I need to firgure out how to make ISO8601 to seconds, but I guess I'll pass on Stack Overflow for now...

*EDIT:* Here, if you are coming from Google, because I couldn't find a direct answer of how to make the YouTube duration string to seconds, I made this from pieces:

```
$VideoId = "dQw4w9WgXcQ"

[String]$gdata_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$VideoId&key=<APIKEY>&part=contentDetails"

$metadata = irm $gdata_uri
$duration = $metadata.items.contentDetails.duration;
echo $duration

$ts = [Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan("$duration")
'{0:00},{1:00},{2:00}.{3:00}' -f ($ts.Hours+$ts.Days*24), $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds, $ts.Milliseconds

$timespan = [TimeSpan]::Parse($ts)
$totalSeconds = $timespan.TotalSeconds
echo $totalSeconds
```

Credits:

- https://gist.github.com/ShinNoNoir/d59ca5da3cd5c554a832
- [Converting ISO8601 (I think) to hours:minutes:seconds in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846943/converting-iso8601-i-think-to-hoursminutesseconds-in-powershell)
- [Calculate total seconds from string in format "HH:mm:ss,fff"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894169/calculate-total-seconds-from-string-in-format-hhmmss-fff)

**Good luck.**

Comment: A very good research and solution, which I tried to work on but got stuck on the API key. Don't give up on SO, here is a link for ISO 8601 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx